# How can I force output strings on the same line?

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a file `serviceOut_live.txt` with this lines:

```
[GC 1028838K->827912K(1305024K), 0.0311954 secs]
```

And I want to convert the file `serviceOut_live.txt` into another file `resul.txt` with this format:

```
1028838 20131030165102
```

This is my code:

```
$input_path = 'c:\a\a\serviceOut_live.txt'

$output_file = 'c:\a\a\resul.txt'

$regex = '\[GC (\d{0,9})K->(\d{0,9})'

echo $(select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % {
  $_.matches[0].groups[1].value , $(get-date -format "yyyyMMddHHmmss")
} ) > $output_file
```

But the result is in two lines:

```
1028838

20131030165102
```

And I want the result in one line:

```
1028838 20131030165102
```

How could I do that?

---

Thank you very much for the tips.
I think that I have not explained myself.
This is the original file:
[GC 1028838K->827912K(1305024K), 0.0311954 secs]
And I want the result in multiple lines:

\n =  carriage return

1028838 20131030165102\n
1028822 20131030165103\n
1029999 20131030165107\n

How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to cast it as [string]:

```
 echo ([string]$(select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches |
  % { $_.matches[0].groups[1].value , $(get-date -format "yyyyMMddHHmmss") } )) > $output_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace each line with a the matched group of digits found after the first space and before the 'K', then concat it with the current date

```
Get-Content $input_path | 
ForEach-Object { ($_ -replace '^\[GC (\d+)K->.*$','$1') +' '+ (get-date -f yyyyMMddHHmmss) } | 
Out-File $output_file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like really long lines (I don't):

```
$(select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches).Matches[0].Groups[1].Value + " " + (get-date -f yyyyMMddHHmmss) > $output_file
```

Note that this also only gets the first match in the file and will fail if no matches can be found.